CD with physical hole is perfectly readable - how?
I am retrieving data from some old optical discs.
I came accross a CD with physical hole about 1 mm in diameter in the data layer. The plastic carrier is fine.
The hole is actually in a place, where data is stored.
But when I have performed a surface scan in ISO Buster and it finished with a success as if nothing was there. The data could be read from the CD as well.
I am aware, that the filesystems for optical drives could employ redundancy, but was that optional back then (15+ years ago) or was every disc burned that way... so it actually stored more than 700 MB of raw data?
But the more mindblowing part for me was, that the ISO Buster surface scan haven't noticed it. Any idea why?

How do you know that there is actually data where the hole is?

While CD do contain a lot of error correction (Yes, even back then), having a real hole that large would need a lot of luck to not stamp out whole blocks. So, are you sure the 'hole' really falls in an occupied data area? After all, CD's aren't formatted all the way like disks are. CDs are more like tapes, only used area is written with a format. Any check will only read those areas, nothing else. They can not check unassigned areas. How much data does it contain? Could you add a picture? Also information about type used?

@tofro haha... now I am just wondering whether I am missing something or you are too young to know how optical discs work ... the disk is written from inside out and the process or "burning" the data onto it changes its color a little, so by looking at the CD from the bottom, you can actually tell how much of it is filled with data.

If it's a CD and not a CD-R, then the data is there on the polycarbonate body of the disk. The reflective metal layer might be missing (if that's what you called a hole in data layer), but the reflections off the pits and lands still might produce enough variations in signal for data to be read successfully.

I recall the CD for Native Instruments FM7 (a software synthesizer) had two physical holes in it, as a copy-protection mechanism. The CD had the instrument itself (a couple dozen MB) plus a several-hundred MB file of what I assume was random data, the latter covering the region where the holes on the CD were. The installer required that file to be present, and presumably verified some checksums from the readable parts of it. Most CD-copying utilities would fail to clone it, as the drive would spin down whenever it met one of the holes.

@LukášŘádek Now I'm feeling very old, because CDs are somewhat "modern" to me :) But thanks for assuming I'm "too young" :)

@Vlad it is a CD-R, the data was written "at home", it is not pressed CD

@Raffzahn image is probably not needed. You can easily imagine it as a clean well defined 1x1 hole about 1,5cm from the inner circumference of the reflective layer. I assume that the hole is through the data because written parts of the disc always changed color and the colorchange is further out... around 3 cm from the inner circumference. Regarding the software not reading the unassigned areas... ISO Buster presents it as a CD Surface scan, which (from the name) I would assume to check the whole dics. I am wondering if that is possible though...does the software has access to the "raw" disc?

@LukášŘádek Even if possible for a software to read a "raw" sector with 2352 lightly error-corrected bytes of audio, for a data disc it would just read the sectors in Mode 1 Data mode which returns only the heavily error-corrected 2048 bytes.

@LukášŘádek Well, in that case, why didn't you add this information in the first place (RC.SE is not a chatty Forum) - likewise that it's not about CD, but CD-R? THis is important, as CD-R can skip areas. Last but not least, there is no 'whole surface' of a CD - only the written part. Nothing behind that can be checked in a meaningful way. There is no 'raw' disk. The unwritten parts are non existent, thus can't e checked. No mater what software. Think of a CD as a tape (as that is what CD design is based on). What is o a tape behind the last recording? Nothing. So no way to check it.

By itself, the wording of that Question not only suggests, but almost insists that this is pure luck… had the hole been the least bit sideways, up or down might have made all the difference. Without specific measurements, what more could there be to this?

I rejected an edit that was trying to add the 'repair' tag to the question; the question is not about repairing anything.

@RobbieGoodwin There is no more to it. The error correction is that good and even better. There are even special test CDs which can test if the player works with various lengths of breaks in the data.

@Justme Can you say how that helps this Question, or how it works in general English?
Doubtless other opinions abound, and mine is still that what happens after a CD gets a physical hole is purely a matter of luck.
Who doubts that please, explain how?

@RobbieGoodwin It is not a matter of luck. CDs are by specification required to have error correction and 1mm is by specification below that threshold, if there are no other errors such as scratches. See the answers for details.

Uh… who told you CDs are 'by specification' required to have error correction and 1mm is by specification below that threshold, if there are no other errors such as scratches?

Could not this be a multi-session CD-R on which probably by default only the last session is being checked?

That's the power of multiple systems and layers or error checking and correction working together. I would actually expect that a single 1mm hole has no real effect on a data disc.
First of all, the raw data on CD is interleaved. Which means that a single 1mm break is not a single 1mm break on the data stream, but it affects multiple small pieces of different parts of the data stream due to interleaving.
The CD uses CIRC or Cross Interleaves Reed Solomon Code which can handle up to 2.5mm gap and can correct the errors. Longer gaps up to 7.5mm can be detected and compensated if the sectors contain audio, by interpolating between the audio samples that are flagged as erroneous. The CIRC works on two error correction levels on the raw audio data sectors.
When the CD sector contains data instead of audio, there is a third layer of error correction. The sector for raw audio data of 2352 bytes is divided into 16 bytes of header, 2048 bytes of actual data, and 288 bytes of error checking and correction data.
So it's not the file system that offers the redundancy - it might depending on the file system, but there's quite a bit of redundancy built-in to the non-audio data sectors themselves, and even to raw sectors not used for formatted data but raw audio data.
So if a CD is defined to have 74 minutes of audio, that's 333000 sectors, almost 747 MB in audio data of 2352 bytes per sector, but only 640 MB in Mode 1 data sectors of 2048 bytes per sector. This means that there's 75 sectors per second.
And even one sector is really comprised of 98 sub-frames, containing 33 bytes each, of which 24 are sector audio data, 8 are error correction data, and 1 byte is subcode data for P, Q and other subcode channels from S to W.

Interleaving is the one piece of the puzzle I didn't know about in optical CD / DVD data storage.  That makes a lot of sense, as physical damage like scratches are likely to be localized, which would be the worst case for per-block forward error correction without interleaving.  (vs. something like PAR2 global error correction across all sectors, where you'd prefer a couple completely destroyed sectors and the rest with no errors so you can use them.  But that's not feasible for real-time playback, or for data access without enough RAM or other storage to reconstruct the whole thing.)

Sounds interesting, thank you. This is not an audio CD, just to complete the picture. I was rather more surprised, that the ISO Buster surface scan did not complain about it. Do I understand it correctly, that the error corrections that you talk about are happening on a lower level, so once the data reaches the software, there is no fault detectable? Meaning that Windows programs (possibly) don't have access to the raw CD data?

@LukášŘádek Like I explained, data CDs are built on top of Audio CDs, and even Audio CDs have enough error correction data to recover 1mm holes, and data CDs have even more error correction. When your program wants to read a non-raw data sector, it will not receive any indication there even was an error, as the CD drive has already corrected the error succesfully and there is no error reading the sector. Your windows program may have access to raw data sector but if you want to read a data CD it usually makes no sense to tell the drive to read you the raw data.
